# Can somebody explain the return value of gets() in C?

Tags: c, gets

I am trying to find out the return value of function gets() in C, but i didn't understand it!

I read in some books: Returns its argument if successful. A NULL pointer indicates an error or end-of-file condition.

But the argument is a pointer to a char array. And as i understood right, the return value is also a char-pointer?

For example:

```
int main(void)
{
   char text[20];
   char *c = 0;

   printf("Please enter a text: ");
   gets(text);
   printf("Output: %s\n",text);
   printf("Return Value: %p\n",c);

   return 0;
}
```

If i type in "hello world!" i got as output

Output: hello world!
Return Value: 00000000

If i understand right, the return value shows a null pointer which means an error!?

Please help!

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with the return value. It just assumes that it will magically appear in the `c` variable.

Comment: not an answer but worth reading; from the man: `Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to  store  characters
       past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer security.  Use fgets() instead.`

Comment: @ledi001 Please google first.

Comment: I don’t see the relation between your use of Gets and the last print you made.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to store the *return value* of `fgets` into `c`, so it prints whatever it was initialized with.

> **Return Value**
>   On success, the function returns `str`.
>   If the end-of-file is encountered while attempting to read a character, the eof indicator is set (`feof`). If this happens before any characters could be read, the pointer returned is a null pointer (and the contents of str remain unchanged).
>   If a read error occurs, the error indicator (`ferror`) is set and a null pointer is also returned (but the contents pointed by `str` may have changed).
>   (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/)

Fixed code shows it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char text[20];
   char *c = 0;

   printf("Please enter a text: ");
   c = gets(text);
   printf("Output: %s\n",text);
   printf("Return Value: %p\n",c);

   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
Please enter a text: hello
Output: hello
Return Value: 0x7fff66df0a30
```

Entering `^D` (EOF on my OS; `^Z` on some other systems) shows some random characters because the array `text` contains uninitialized data, and you are printing it *anyway*:

```
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
Please enter a text: Output: &???
Return Value: 0x0
```

but then prints the expected 'return value' `0`.

(That warning is automatically inserted by my compiler, clang. Better heed it; you can see why it emits the warning when you enter more than 18 characters.)